# Prove inequality for $a, b , c, d$ for $a,b, c, d\ge 0$

Tags: inequality

How does one prove the following inequality:
$$ \frac{a}{a^2+1}+\frac{b}{b^2+1}+\frac{c}{c^2+1}+\frac{d}{d^2+1}\le\frac{a}{b^2+1}+\frac{b}{c^2+1}+\frac{c}{d^2+1}+\frac{d}{a^2+1}$$
without much computation? Is there a trick?

Comment: I would show that it is true with two variables, and then show that generalization doesn't break down when you add a 3rd or a 4th.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is.

You can consider the numbers $a,b,c,d$ on one side and the numbers $\frac1{a^2+1}$, $\frac1{b^2+1}$, $\frac1{c^2+1}$, $\frac1{d^2+1}$ on the other, and apply the [Rearrangement Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality).

Comment: Do I have to assume that $a>b>c>d$?

Comment: Yes. Or the reverse order. Or *any* order, And the inequalities don't have to be strict.

Comment: @hetjar: One can also say the same thing by stating $(a, b, c, d)$ and $(\frac{1}{a^2+1}, \frac{1}{b^2+1}, \frac{1}{c^2+1}, \frac{1}{d^2+1})$ are oppositely sorted; that is, any nonstrict inequality which holds between a pair of terms in the first tuple is flipped when considering corresponding terms in the second tuple.